# Disable Sass vendor prefix autocomplete

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

How can I disable the VSCode from generating vendor prefixed style properties when trying to tab in a property without vendor prefixes added?  I don't need the vendor prefixes as my post-css post processing for Sass handles this already.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK that's not the default behaviour. Do you have any additional SASS-related extensions installed?

Comment: @kwood, not when this was happening, although I recently installed "Sass"

Comment: it would be good to have an option to disable vendor prefixes at all, like all of them is just does not exist

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe, as far as I understand it, is not the default behavior of VScode. In SCSS/SASS syntax modes, there is no vendor prefix autocomplete. This is most likely caused by an additional code snippet plugin for the language or a CSS autoprefix plugin.

I recommend disabling all SCSS/SASS-related plugins, then checking if those vendor prefixes still show up. It is very likely that they do not. You should then re-enable the disabled plugins one by one until you hit the culprit. Just leave the conflicting plugin disabled or remove it and you should be set.

When you are starting with a hyphen, you are triggering auto completion as expected. There is very little you can do about it because this is expected behavior.

To get the behavior you strive for, there's really only two alternatives:

- Ask the plugin author to make vendor prefix completion optional, behind a user setting.
- [Fork the plugin](https://github.com/robinbentley/vscode-sass-indented), change [the respective source code](https://github.com/robinbentley/vscode-sass-indented/blob/master/src/schemas/cssSchema.ts) by deleting the completions you don't want, build it and replace the upstream version with your version in VScode. You can easily install plugins from local `.vsix` plugin package files.

**Update:** Just to make things easier for you, I have gone ahead, stripped all vendor prefixes and packaged the plugin. You can download it here: https://github.com/herrbischoff/vscode-sass-indented-stripped

Comment: here is my installed extensions list and there is no CSS plugins https://gist.github.com/Grawl/27a1bc6af531734218e36474581df332

Comment: and here is my settings https://gist.github.com/Grawl/efa31d7fbf261dfdcd6d54cf75e60a25

Comment: but everytime I write indented Sass and trying to get autocomplete on selector I get all existing vendor prefixes https://imgur.com/a/dqhMU

Comment: Even if I do not write anything in `.sass` file (like `&-`) I got vendor prefixes list in suggestions

Comment: The screenshot made your case clear. You apparently expect to not see vendor prefixes when you **start with a hyphen**. I will update my answer with further information.

Comment: Check out my updated answer. There's a modified plugin package for you to download that behaves like you expect.

Comment: Thank you! Sad it requires modification. Vendor prefixes **must** be optional.

Comment: You're welcome. I believe this is due to the CSS schema being defined globally. I suggest asking the plugin author if he's willing to make a change, although I doubt it. If you're interested in the modified source code, let me know, I will then update the repo. This may be easier to track upstream changes.